# Why does $\int \sin y\;dx = x \sin y + C$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I've just started to learn calculus on my own. I don't get how $$\int \sin y\;dx = x \sin y + C$$ I've tried to search on Google, but I couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question.

Comment: If we view $y$ as a **constant**, then it is correct, in general $\int k\,dx=kx+C$.

Comment: Are you awrae that $\int a\,\mathrm dx=ax+C$?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int{\sin{x}\;dx}=-\cos{x}+C
$$

But in this case $\sin{y}$ plays role as constant:

$$
\int{\sin {y}\;dx}=\sin{y}\int{dx}=x\sin{y}+C
$$

Comment: it will be xsiny + C.

Answer (score 1):

$\int \sin{y}$ $dx = x\;\sin{y}+C$ because integration and derivatives are inverse functions of one another

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}[x\;\sin{y}+C] &=\frac{d}{dx}[x\;\sin{y}]+\frac{d}{dx}[C]\\
&=\sin{y}\frac{d}{dx}[x]+\frac{d}{dx}[C]\\
&=\sin{y}\times1+0\\
&=\sin{y}
\end{align}
$$

Another way of looking at this is to say that the derivative is the rate of change while the integral is the area under some curve.